# Generate signed apk for React Native Android application using existing certificate

Tags: android, react-native, certificate, apk, keystore

I have an Android app certificate with a file type of FILE that was created back in 2012 for my Android app written in Java. Now I have updated that app using React Native.

How can I use the existing certificate to generate keystore and sign my updated app to be released on Google Play?

I've tried this even though the React Native certificate extension is `.keystore`

```
keytool -importcert -file "your.cer" -keystore your.jks -alias "<anything>"
```

and I got the following error

```
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

I expect to have a `.keystore` file that allows me to release an update of my existing Android app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create `keystore` file. you can use existing jks file to sign the app. Do as follow:

- Put your jks file in the app directory
- add the following code in your gradle.poperties file.

  ```
  MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=filename.jks
  MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=your-key-alias
  MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=your-store-password
  MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=your-release-key-password
  ```
- Now add the signingConfigs in build.gradle file as below:

  ```
  signingConfigs{
      release {
          if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
              storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
              storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
              keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
              keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
          }
      }
  }

  buildTypes {
      release {
          signingConfig signingConfigs.release
      }
  }
  ```
- Now you can sing your using your existing jks file.

Comment: My certificate's file type is FILE how can I convert it to jks ?

Comment: just add yourfilename.jks and try to build it will work.

Comment: You can check the certificate details after apk signed using this command : `unzip -p Name-of-apk.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA | keytool -printcert`

Comment: I've followed all the steps but I could not find the release folder (ie. no generated apk) at ...\android\app\build\outputs\apk

Comment: @GirmaFeyissa is your build successful?

Comment: Yes It does not generate the APK on the first trial. --- after I run gradlew clean build assembleRelease AND gradlew bundleRelease I successfully get the APK. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One thing missed from the accepted answer.

How to fetch the existing Keystore file from the expo?

```
expo fetch:android:keystore
```

I need to know this so hopefully, it'll help someone.